# Resetting permissions in 2008 r2

Tags: permissions

Recently someone made a change to the permissions in one of our directories. This effected every user. There must be a script to fix this all at once instead of one by one.

What changed: the users need full control over their own folders, files and sub folders. This was changed from full control to no rights at all. There are over 800 users. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get-acl and set-acl](http://chrisfederico.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/setting-acl-on-a-file-or-directory-in-powershell/) in PowerShell to set permissions on each directory recursively. A better bet might be to just restore from backup.

There is no "oh shit, I shouldnt have done that" script laying around that's already custom tailored for your environment. If you don't have a good backup and you aren't familiar with scripting, then I'd get to learning pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can back up and restore permissions easily with [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/).

Comment: Not if the damage is already done.

Comment: MDMarra: In that case you can re-set the desired permissions easily with SetACL, too.